# Return if-else statement

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, while-loop

I have a code that contains several if statements, but, i need to return the previous level if the statement is not satisfy. I tried to put on the "else", but the code continues to stoping. I thried to do a While condition " While != 0" but i stucked in a infinity loop
he's my code

```
        print('Voce selecionou - [2] - Utilizar Seleção por ano (12 meses/ano)')
    print('\n [1] - Variáveis atuais do modelo \n')
    print('\n [2] - Importação das variáveis e matriz de correlação \n')
    print('\n [0] - Sair do programa \n')
    atual = int(input('Selecione etapa: '))
    
       
    if atual == 1:
        print('\n As Variáveis do atual modelo são \n')
        colunas = list(dados.columns.values)
        print('\n Os dados atuais são \n')
        for x in colunas:
            print('Variável: %s' % x)
            
    if atual == 2:
        
        print('\n =============================================== \n')    
        print('\n A matriz de correlação é: \n')
        correlacao = dados.corr().round(4).iloc[0]
        print(correlacao)
        
        print('\n As Variaveis dentro da condição de validade são: \n')
        
    if atual == 0:
        print('\n Obrigado por usar esse menu e até a próxima! \n')
        print('\n Norte Energia - Usina Hidrelétrica Belo Monte \n') 
    else:
        print('\n Opção Inexistente \n')
        
if corte == 0:
        print('\n Obrigado por usar esse menu e até a próxima! \n')
        print('\n Norte Energia - Usina Hidrelétrica Belo Monte \n') 
        
else:
    print('\n Opção inexistente \n')
    return
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing the indented 'if' statements with 'elif', don't replace the first 'if' though.

```
if atual == 1:
    print('\n As Variáveis do atual modelo são \n')
    colunas = list(dados.columns.values)
    print('\n Os dados atuais são \n')
    for x in colunas:
        print('Variável: %s' % x)
        
elif atual == 2:
    
    print('\n =============================================== \n')    
    print('\n A matriz de correlação é: \n')
    correlacao = dados.corr().round(4).iloc[0]
    print(correlacao)
    
    print('\n As Variaveis dentro da condição de validade são: \n')
    
elif atual == 0:
    print('\n Obrigado por usar esse menu e até a próxima! \n')
    print('\n Norte Energia - Usina Hidrelétrica Belo Monte \n') 
else:
    print('\n Opção Inexistente \n')
```

I had some problem while creating the fizzbuzz game, not sure if it was the same problem, but replacing the with 'elif' fixed it. Might work for you

Answer (score 0):

Use else-if blocks. 'elif' in python as mentioned by Bibekjit. Along with that use a 'break' statement if you want to come out of the while loop(if certain condition matches).